# How to remove index.php from the URL of MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I used this tool http://shorturls.redwerks.org/ to rewrite a short url for MediaWiki.
From this: `http://wikitest.org/fr/index.php/Accueil` to this: `http://wikitest.org/fr/wiki/Accueil`.

Then I added this code to LocalSettings.php:

```
## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs please see:
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "/fr";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "{$wgScriptPath}/wiki/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true
```

But when I go to my site I get ***404 Not Found***. The resource requested could not be found on this server!

Comment: And how do the rewrite rules on your server look?

Comment: There is no rewrite rules in my server. There is no .htaccess I have only changed the LocalSettings.php to change the URL.

Comment: Then that's why. You need to tell your server to serve something at those urls. LocalSettings.php can only change the links in the wiki, not the behaviour of your server

Answer (score 11):

The changes to `LocalSettings.php` affects only the links in your wiki. You also need to add the proper rewrite rules to your server,so that there is actually something there for the user to see. In your case, adding something like this to `.htaccess` might work, assuming you are running Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?fr/wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/fr*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

You can find detailed instructions for your server in [the manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL).