# Mediawiki .../wiki/Special:Version and other pages redirecting

Tags: mediawiki

Ok, super novice messing with Mediawiki for the first time from a fresh set-up perspective. I've installed version 1.25.2 and am running pretty barebones right now. I'm trying to access my local install's .../wiki/Special:Version page to just get the details and see the list of extensions via GUI.

My wiki is served up fine. I can get to mediawiki itself, what I'm trying to access are the "admin" type pages that are typically served up via .../wiki/... like this: mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Version I can get to my localhost:port/ just fine and hit media wiki. when I try to hit localhost:port/wiki/... that is what redirects me back to the index page of the wiki

Every time I try to hit this page (or any other page under .../wiki/..) it redirects me back to the home page.

My user has the sysops and bureaucrat roles.

Am I completely missing something here?

Here are the details of my Apache2.conf:

```
# see http://sources.debian.net/src/apache2/2.4.10-1/debian/config-

dir/apache2.conf

Mutex file:/var/lock/apache2 default
PidFile /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User www-data
Group www-data
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# ports.conf
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 combined

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

# Multiple DirectoryIndex directives within the same context will add
# to the list of resources to look for rather than replace
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex
DirectoryIndex disabled
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
Include /etc/apache2/mediawiki.conf
```

And here is the mediawiki.conf file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/images>
  # Ignore .htaccess files
  AllowOverride None

  # Serve HTML as plaintext, don't execute SHTML
  AddType text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php

  # Don't run arbitrary PHP code.
  php_admin_flag engine off
</Directory>
```

Comment: Looks like apache redirect to me, not a mediawiki configuration. Have you checked it?

Comment: I don't see anything in my apache2.conf file that would indicate as such.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you havn't told Apache to serve your wiki under `/wiki/`!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove index.php from the URL of MediaWiki?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024848/how-to-remove-index-php-from-the-url-of-mediawiki)

Comment: My wiki is served up fine. I can get to mediawiki itself, what I'm trying to access are the "admin" type pages that are typically served up via .../wiki/... like this: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Version

I can get to my localhost:port/ just fine and hit media wiki. when I try to hit localhost:port/wiki/... that is what redirects me back to the index page of the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was all on me. I was trying to access these pages via localhost:port/wiki/Special:Version when I need to actually hit localhost:port/index.php/Special:Version.

So yes, leo was correct, thanks.